# Is there a difference between these two CSS notations for applying a style to a certain class?

Tags: html, css

I've seen the following two notations on CSS pages, and they *seem* to work the same, *is* there a difference between them?

```
.ClassName  a:hover
```

And:

```
a.ClassName:hover
```

Comment: I'm interested to see the page where these work the same...

Comment: `<div class="ClassName"><a class="ClassName">Bupp</a></div>`

Comment: @Esailija it could be as simple as both the `<a>` and one of its ancestors having the same class applied in the markup.

Comment: @MattBall yes theoretically you can do that, but a real website actually having it?

Comment: @Esailija Wow. Lots of answers. Anyway, I didn't mean both were on the _same_ web page. I just meant: each on its own page. I guess I should've written "on CSS pages".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between them.

`.ClassName a:hover` refers to any hovered anchor that is within an element with `class="ClassName"`.

`a.ClassName:hover`, however, refers to any hovered anchor that **has** `class="ClassName"`.

There is lots of information regarding [CSS Selectors at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Comment: What MrSlayer said. It sounds, though, like the OP's HTML might be a little screwy, if both selectors are performing the same way.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I didn't mean both were on the _same_ web page. I just meant: each on its own page. I guess I should've written "on CSS pages". Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

```
.ClassName  a:hover //this applies to all child `a` elements of `ClassName`
<div class="ClassName">
  <a>link</a>
</div>

a.ClassName:hover //this applies to the `a` elements that have `ClassName` class
<div>
  <a class="ClassName">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> a.ClassName:hover

```
<a class="ClassName" href="#">fff</a>
```

> .ClassName  a:hover

```
<div class="ClassName">
  <a href="#">fff</a>
</div>
```

First approach works only for `<a>` elements with class `ClassName`.

Second approach, class can be used for any element and if that element contains `<a>` hover property will be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there absolutely is a difference.

- The first matches hovered anchors which are descendants of elements with class `ClassName`.
- The second matches hovered anchors with class `ClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

**.ClassName  a:hover** means `anchor` inside `.ClassName` . it's

HTML

```
<div class="ClassName ">
 <a></a>
</div>
```

**OR**

**a.ClassName:hover** means `.ClassName` with `anchor`. It's

HTML

```
<a vlass="ClassName"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first modifies the `hover` property for any link inside any element that has `ClassName` applied.

The second is for any `a` that has `ClassName` applied, irrespective of any closing containers or tags.